# Mongoose - fire event after creation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB with `mongoose` package.

I'm saving records in the database every few seconds, but I would like to fire an event after 24h after the creation of that record. Is there some clever way of doing this?

I could create a loop that checks all the records every n secs, but this is not efficient at all.

Comment: You might overestimate inefficiency. If you have constant flow of inserts with interval of n seconds, you are going to execute some code every n seconds  anyway, even if the timer is triggered externally.

Answer (score 1):

You should be used `Cron Job` on your system, the job initiated after you done specific task , please check it out .May be it helps you.

https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron

Comment: Hmm, so there is no specific mongoose function. I'm worried that I will have to scan the collection every x seconds to look for records that were created 24 or more hours before the event is fired.

Comment: @Ancinek, there is no need to scan whole collection. Create an index on the date field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Change Stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) to listen for data changes in your collection, and react to them as required.

You will need to write an application to do the listening, and fire the event with a 24-hour delay - perhaps using a standard job queue module.

Comment: He changes the data himself. The "24-hour delay" remains, you just shift it from original data change point to the listener of ChangeStram events. The question is really about this "standard job queue module". I believe the OP will appreciate if you elaborate on this point.